# Index page stops working as soon as I add sqlite()

Tags: php, database, sqlite

Page works fine until I add

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
      function __construct() {
         $this->open('test.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db) {
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

I don't get an error message, nothing. Page won't even load.
I have the full LAMP stack installed.And `phpinfo()` validates the existence of sqlite. What else am I missing?

Comment: When you add that do you get a 500 status code? The error logs are empty? Error logging is enabled?

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 3 lines to the top of any script you want to debug `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Dave `display errors` should NOT be used in a LIVE environment.